# Uniqueness for Integral Transform

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integral-transforms

What can be said about the uniqueness of the following integral transformation:

$ (Tf)(u) = \int_0^{\infty} f(t)G(tu)dt$ defined for all $u\geq 0$,

where the kernel $G(z) \in [0,1]$ for all $z\geq0$, and it is monotonically decreasing from 1 to 0 as its argument goes from 0 to $\infty$.

Let $f(t)$ and $h(t)$ are two probability distributions. Suppose they have the same transform, i.e., $ (Tf)(u) = (Th)(u)$ for all $u\geq 0$? Does this imply uniqueness, i.e. $f(t)=g(t)$ for all $t\geq0$?

Comment: If $K(t,u) = c(u)$, for some function $u \mapsto c(u)$, then $(Tf)(u) = c(u)$ for all probability distributions.

Comment: After your edit, @copper.hat's comment still applies, if you take $K(u) = c$ for a fixed constant $c$. Then $K(tu) = K(u) = c$ and again $(Tf)(u) = (Tg)(u) = c$ for any two probability distributions $f,g$.

Comment: A difficult question. Nobody can answer that.

Comment: Maybe this could help, the Lerch theorem: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchsTheorem.html