# Expectation and Uniqueness

Tags: probability

Let Y and Z be two nonnegative random variables (RVs). Let $f(x) \in [0,1]$ for all $x\geq0$, and it is monotonically decreasing from 1 to 0 as its argument goes from 0 to $\infty$.

If $E_Y\{f(aX)\}=E_Z\{f(aZ)\}$ for all $a\geq 0$, does this imply Y and Z have the same PDF?

More precisely, if the PDFs are $\phi_Y(x)$ and $\phi_Z(x)$, and if
$\int_0^{\infty}f(ax)[\phi_Y(x)-\phi_Z(x)]dx=0$ for all $a\geq 0$, does this imply $\phi_Y=\phi_Z$?

note:  $E_Y\{\cdot\}$ denotes expectation over the RV Y.

Comment: If the pdfs are $\phi_x,\phi_y$ then you are asking does $$\int_\mathbb{R} z f(az) \left[ \phi_x(z) - \phi_y(z) \right] dz = 0 \quad \forall a \geq 0$$ imply that $\phi_x = \phi_y$.

Comment: Is $f$ continuous? Otherwise, if $f(0) =1$ and $f(x) = 0 \ \forall x > 0$, this would not be sufficient...

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407377/uniqueness-for-integral-transform)?

Comment: I guess it is a difficult question. Nobody can answer that.

Comment: Even the smartest math Professor Terence Tao, himself